# Grails controllers dynamic finders

Tags: grails, controllers

I'm kinda new to Grails so I need help with this matter. Imagine I have these classes:

```
Class User{
String name
String nr

}

class Computer{

String processor
String ram
User user
}

Class Room{
String roomNr
Computer computer
}
```

I want to do a controller like this:

```
def print= {

        def user = User.get(1)

        def computer = Computer.findAllByUser(user) // all computers filtered by User

        [computer: computer]       
    }
```

The controller works good, but I want to be able to pass not only the computer instances, but also the Room's with that computer id's. I dont know how to do it, but would be something like this (same controller, same action):

def print= {

```
        def user = User.get(1)

        def computer = Computer.findAllByUser(user) // all computers filtered by User
        def room = Room.findAllByComputer(computer) ##

        [computer: computer]       
    }
```

Well, this is wrong because, where the ### is, 'computer' represents a list of id's and not a single id. As I am passing a list of computers to be printed in my gsp inside a g: each tag like this: (it. Processor, it. Ram). I dont know how to get all the rooms which are using the current computer in the each tag. This is a bit hard to explain, but basically my output would be:

```
<g:each in="${computer}"
Computer1:
Processor: ${it.processor}
Ram: ${it.ram}
Room: ????? (How to get here??)
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like this, but I didn't test it.

Controller:

```
def print = {

  def user = User.get(1)
  def computer = Computer.findAllByUser(user)
  def rooms = [:]

  // get rooms for that computer
  computer.each{

    def computerRooms = Room.findAllByComputer(it) // find all rooms where current computer is
    rooms.put(it.id, computerRooms) // map all the rooms with computer id

  }

  [computer: computer, rooms: rooms]      
}
```

View:

```
<g:each in="${computer}">
  Computer1:
  Processor: ${it.processor}
  Ram: ${it.ram}
  Rooms: <g:join in="${rooms[it.id]}" delimiter=", "/>
</g:each>
```

Rooms map uses computer id as a key and list of all rooms where that computer is as value. Of course If I understood you correctly ;)

### EDIT

If you need access room details, you can replace `join` tag with another `each` tag, like this:

```
<g:each in="${computer}" >
  Computer1:
  Processor: ${it.processor}
  Ram: ${it.ram}
  Rooms: <br/>
  <g:each in="${rooms[it.id]}">
    Room id: ${it.id}
    Room number: ${it.number}
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

And you can also implement the `Room` class `toString()` method, because `join` tag uses it to render text:

```
Class Room{
  String roomNr
  ...

  String toString(){
    roomNr
  }
}
```

Now when you use `join` tag on list of `Room` class instances, it will print room number.

Comment: how can i access each attribute of room separatly? like it.roomNr and more.. ?

Comment: i do like this: <g:join in="${rooms[it.roomNr]}" delimiter=", "/>
 ?

Comment: thank you:P gone try it now :p But it really seems thats the perfect answer i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

make the relationship bidirectional.   Right now you store which Room has which Computer, but you don't go the other way, so you can follow a Computer to its Room.  Check out

http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html

specifically section 5.2.1.2, on bidirectional one-to-many relationships.

Be aware that Grails is build on best of breed technologies.   One of those is hibernate.  Being familiar with the underlying technologies will only help you.

So after all that, what I am getting at is your Computer class should have a reference to the Room that it is in.  The Room class should have a list of Computers (assuming more than one computer can be in a room).  The difficulty you will have is in understanding the cascading behaviour of hibernate, which depends on how you set up the relationship.  If you run into trouble update this question or start a new one with the specific issue.

Comment: @Richard: I agree with hvgotcodes. The problem should disappear after you rework the domain class.

Comment: i dont think that will work, because, a room can have no computers. So if i have a foreign key in room table, i need to have a relation to computers table. which can or not happen.

Comment: there must be a simple way to work around with my current code. Any idea please :P ?

Comment: @richard, how many computers can be in a room? 0,1, or more than one.  Can a Computer exist without a Room?  Take the check mark off this answer until it is solved.

Comment: a computer cannot exist without a room. A room can have 0, 1 ou + computers.

Comment: If room can have many computers, you should write: 
Room{
...
  static hasMany = [computers: Computer]
}

Comment: yes. My classes are much more complex that this.. I just shorted it because my main problem is this one. I only need to pass in the controller the rooms that contain each computer to be able to print it on the view. The problem is, how can get that?

Comment: @richard, its no problem if a Room has no computers.  You should make Room -> Computer a one to many, (jjczopek shows you how in comment above).  The foreign key is in Computer, not Room.  And you should have a Computer point to the room its in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't send the room variable to the view

```
[computer: computer]
```

Should be:

```
[computer:computer, room:room]
```

Comment: lol yes i know that :P But i need to filter the rooms by computer id. that is the problem and i dont know how to do it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <g:set> to acquire a room reference inside your <g:each>.  That way, the controller is not concerned with rooms.  Generally, I like to gather all pertinent information that feeds the GSP in the controller, but there are exceptions, as in the case of some ancillary details.